Transliteration issues vis-à-vis topolect?
I would like to find some papers that discuss transliteration issues vis-à-vis topolect.
One example being: translating 旺角 as Wang Jiao in English, would be completely incorrect. Yet, this runs counter to set conventions, i.e.: transliterating into English using MSM.
In fact, Hong Kong's general names of geographical areas could all be up for discussion as potential areas of conflict.
I would imagine that with the amount of different topolectical readings, only using MSM to transliterate would cause issues.
Ideas?

I think that you could include 2 or 3 transliterations and maybe even IPA in English text. Example: "We will visit 旺角 (Cantonese: Jyutping: Wong6 Gok3, IPA: /wɔːŋ²² kɔːk̚³/; Mandarin: Hanyu Pinyin: Wàngjiǎo, IPA: /wɑŋ⁵¹ t͡ɕi̯ɑʊ̯²¹⁴⁻²¹⁽⁴⁾/)."
